# Serializing object that inherits from List<T>

Tags: c#, serialization

When I try to serialize this collection, the name property is not serialized.

```
public class BCollection<T> : List<T> where T : B_Button
{       
   public string Name { get; set; }
}


BCollection<BB_Button> bc = new BCollection<B_Button>();

bc.Name = "Name";// Not Serialized!

bc.Add(new BB_Button { ID = "id1", Text = "sometext" });

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(bc);
```

Only if I create a new class (without `List<t>` inheritance), and define there string `Name` property and `List<B_Button> bc = new List<B_Button>();` property I get the right result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In many serializers (and data-binding, in fact), an object is **either** an entity **or** (exclusive) a list; having properties *on* a list is not commonly supported. I would refactor to *encapsulate* the list:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    private readonly List<T> items = new List<T>();
    public List<T> Items { get { return items; } }
}
```

Also; how would you plan on representing that in JSON? IIRC the JSON array syntax doesn't allow for extra properties *either*.

Comment: I just use that to pass data to client (scriptcontrol) where I deserialize it and retrieve the data.