# Serializing object when the object inherits from List<T>

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Public fields/properties of a class derived from BindingList<T> wont serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225750/public-fields-properties-of-a-class-derived-from-bindinglistt-wont-serialize)

When I try to serialize this object, only the list property is serialized.

object code:

```
public class checkList<T>: List<T>
{
        public bool check = true;
        public string path;
        public string type;
}
```

I have a Instance to serialize:

```
List<checkList<Keys>> hookKeys;
```

deserialize code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("list", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<checkList<Keys>>));
hookKeys = (List<checkList<Keys>>)ser.Deserialize(fs);
fs.Close();
```

serialize code:

```
FileStream fsK = new FileStream("list", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
XmlSerializer serK = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<checkList<Keys>>));
serK.Serialize(fsK, (List<checkList<Keys>>)hookKeys);
fsK.Close();
```

xml file after the serializing:

```
<ArrayOfArrayOfKeys xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ArrayOfKeys>
<Keys>X</Keys>
<Keys>Z</Keys>
<Keys>C</Keys>
</ArrayOfKeys>
</ArrayOfArrayOfKeys>
```

how I serialize the other property too?

Comment: What would you expect the resulting XML to look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public fields/properties of a class derived from BindingList<T> wont serialize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225750/public-fields-properties-of-a-class-derived-from-bindinglistt-wont-serialize), also [Serializing object that inherits from List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105762/serializing-object-that-inherits-from-listt?rq=1)

Comment: I want to serilaizing the object property (check, path, type) in the xml file also.

Comment: I thing may be using 'base' and Override List<T> method? but I don't Know which!